# Strict fmap using only Functor, not Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, strictness

One irritation with lazy IO caught to my attention recently

```
import System.IO
import Control.Applicative

main = withFile "test.txt" ReadMode getLines >>= mapM_ putStrLn
  where getLines h = lines <$> hGetContents h
```

Due to lazy IO, the above program prints nothing. So I imagined this could be solved with a strict version of `fmap`. And indeed, I did come up with just such a combinator:

```
forceM :: Monad m => m a -> m a
forceM m = do v <- m; return $! v

(<$!>) :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
f <$!> m = liftM f (forceM m)
```

Replacing `<$>` with `<$!>` does indeed alleviate the problem. However, I am not satisfied. `<$!>` has a `Monad` constraint, which feels too tight; it's companion `<$>` requires only `Functor`.

**Is there a way to write `<$!>` without the `Monad` constraint?** If so, how? If not, why not? I've tried throwing strictness all over the place, to no avail (following code *does not* work as desired):

```
forceF :: Functor f => f a -> f a
forceF m = fmap (\x -> seq x x) $! m

(<$!>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
f <$!> m = fmap (f $!) $! (forceF $! m)
```

Comment: "(\x -> seq x x)" is precisely `id`, so that doesn't help.

Comment: This seems a very strange definition of <$!> to me.   I'd go with "f <$!> m = forceM (liftM f m)"  instead.   This also solves your problem,  and seems a lot more sensible in other contexts.  I suspect you can't define this for functors, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, and also the monadic `forceM` doesn't work for all monads:

```
module Force where

import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

forceM :: Monad m => m a -> m a
forceM m = do v <- m; return $! v

(<$!>) :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
f <$!> m = liftM f (forceM m)

test :: Int
test = evalState (const 1 <$!> undefined) True
```

And the evaluation:

```
Prelude Force> test
1
```

`forceM` needs a strict enough `(>>=)` to actually force the result of its argument. `Functor` doesn't even have a `(>>=)`. I don't see how one could write an effective `forceF`. (That doesn't prove it's impossible, of course.)